# Excel/Statistics Issue

Tags: excel, math, statistics, probability, exponential

I have a homework assignment where I need to run 1000 simulations in excel using an exponential distribution. I'm not sure how to get excel to give me the data I need. This is the question (the first part, at least):

[image: Here is the question]

I've figured out how to use the exponential distribution formula in excel, but I can't get it to return any values greater than 1. I think it's just the nature of that function, but I can't figure out how to get Excel to display the simulated lifetimes of the components. Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has and hasn't worked?

Comment: Nothing has really worked! I've tried using the expondist() function but it calls for 3 parameters: x, lambda, and cumulative. I know lambda is the parameter that controls the functions behavior, but x is supposed to be a time. I'm pretty sure Exp(1) means lambda is one, for example, when the component in question is A. What I want is a (sort of) random output of the component lifetimes, but I'm not sure how to use this weird function.

Answer (score 0):

> with λ in cell N4, the formula =-1/$N$4*LN(1-RAND()) yields a random number from the exponential distribution with parameter λ

from http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/0806%20generate%20random%20numbers.shtml